# WildFly and resource exclusion

Tags: java, spring, jpa, wildfly

I have a wildfly war application at hands, which depends on a jar which starts its own JPA persistence container with Spring. This jar has its own `persistence.xml`, with  only one persistence unit.
In the embedded jar, since there is only one persistence unit, it is injected using a `@PersistenceContext` without a unit name. Furthermore, the objects having such fields are not EJBs, they are simple Spring beans...

On the other hand, the application has also a `persistence.xml` with two persistence units.
The code of the application has `@PersistenceContext` fields with a proper `unitName`, which is mandatory since there are two of them.

Now, when I start my application, Wildfly (specifically the jpa module) scans the code from the jar and chokes on the `@PersistenceContext` without unitNames of my Spring beans:

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa.messages] (MSC service thread 1-1) persistence unit search for unitName=null referenced from class=the.spring.Bean (annotation=@javax.persistence.PersistenceContext() on void the.spring.Bean.setEntityManager(javax.persistence.EntityManager))
```

To cope with this, I would like to exclude the jar: In TomEE there is a mean to exclude a jar explicitly from being scanned, but I cannot find a similar functionnality in WildFly.
I have tried the following configurations without success:

- `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` which is read but without noticeable effect:

  ```
  <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
      <exclusions>
        <module name="deployment.jee-app.war.spring-app.jar" />
        <!-- I have also tried the following -->
        <!-- <module name="jee-app.war.spring-app.jar" /> -->
        <!-- <module name="spring-app.jar" /> -->
      </exclusions>
    </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
  ```
- `jboss-scanning.xml` which seems to be ignored

  ```
  <scanning xmlns="urn:jboss:scanning:1.0">
    <path name="jee-app.war/WEB-INF/lib">
      <exclude name="spring-app.jar" />
    </path>
  </scanning>
  ```

Both of these files are in the WEB-INF folder of my war application.

```
jee-app.war
  ├── WEB-INF
  │   ├── classes
  |   │   ├── META-INF
  |   │   |    └── persistence.xml _____________ # 2 PUs here
  |   |   └── < lots of packages >
  |   ├── lib
  |   |   ├── spring-app.jar ___________________ # to EXCLUDE from scanning !!!
  |   |   |   ├── META-INF
  |   |   |   |   └── persistence
  |   |   |   |       └── persistence.xml ______ # 1 PU here, loaded by Spring
  |   |   |   ├── application.xml ______________ # Spring definition
  |   |   |   └── the
  |   |   |       └── spring
  |   |   |           └── Bean.class
  |   |   └── < lots of other jars > 
  |   ├── jboss-deployment-structure.xml
  |   ├── jboss-scanning.xml
  |   └── web.xml
  └── < some JSPs >
```

Of course, I cannot modify the spring-app.jar (would be too easy...)

Needless to say, I have spend a considerable amount of time in the WildFly doc and on Google without finding anything else than exluding subsystems, or overriding locally modules of WildFly...

Thanks for your help!

Juan Manuel

**EDIT: As per request, here are the persistence.xml files**

The one in the jee-app.war:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="PU1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DS1</jta-data-source>
    <class>...</class> <!-- a lot of classes included by name !-->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

  <persistence-unit name="PU2" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DS2</jta-data-source>
    <class>...</class> <!-- a lot of classes included by name !-->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The one in the spring-app.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="xa-rm">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/persistence/orm.xml</mapping-file>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

  </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: can you paste persistence.xml?

Comment: I edited the question with the persistence.xml files' content

Comment: @JuanManuel Were you able to solve this problem? Because we're encountering a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932015/wildfly-and-resource-exclusion

Comment: Sorry, I did not come here often lately :/ No the issue is still opened so far, we had to repackage the offending jar... Very cumbersome...